# jQuery action whenever any select is changed

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how can I make it so that a function is called whenever any select object on the page is changed?

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the `change` event to all the `select` elements on the DOM:

```
$('select').change(function () {
  // do something
});
```

Inside the event handler, the `this` keyword refers to the `select` element triggered the event, and you can get it's attributes, eg. `var selectId = this.id;`

Comment: +1; Also, use `live(event, action);` if you need to use it for dynamically created objects.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, unfortunately the `change` event is not supported by `live`... yet... http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_1.4_Roadmap#Events

Comment: That was my problem, I used that same code, but all my select object are dynamically created.  Is there a way to still do this?

Comment: @Brian: How do you create your `select` elements?, the event can be bound just after they are inserted on the DOM...

Comment: I get them from ajax functions and insert them into the HTML of spans.  How do I bind that event?